# Is there possibility to use optional by checking reference to object instead of method result?

Tags: guava, option-type

I have following code:

```
if(myObject != null){
    return myObject.foo();
}else{ 
    return "default";
}
```

I would like to use optional from guava but calling foo() can result in NPE (since mObject may by null). 
Does anyone knows how to do it or other way to avoid if statement?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - what would be null? If you could give an example of the code that fails, that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet clarified question

Comment: Well you still haven't shown how you're *trying* to use `Optional`. For example, you can use `Optional.fromNullable`. But it's not clear what the advantage is here. Why not just use `return myObject != null ? myObject.foo() : "default";`. Where would you expect the advantage of `Optional` to be?

Comment: If I use `fromNullable(myObject.foo())` then it can result in null pointer. I was wondering is there would be an option to us it like `Optional.fromNullable(myObject).foo()` but it would require reflection to implement such behavior.

Comment: So you want the *result* to be an `Optional<String>`? I thought you wanted `myOptional` to be an `Optional<Something>`. This is just an indication of how unclear the question is. Please edit your question to make it *much* clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Dont forget about com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull - might be better suited for this usecase than Optional.

Comment: @CodeRunner No, `Objects.firstNonNull(myObject.foo(), "default")` will throw an NPE, since it's `myObject` which is null and not the result of `foo()`.

Comment: @Frank I know, it is not a perfect match and would require some refactoring, but it might be better suited to achieve what pixel wants, e.g. Objects.firstNonNull(myObject, newlyIntroducedNullObjectOrAnonymousClass).foo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet points out, you haven't said what benefits you expect from using `Optional`.

You'll get the same result as the original code with

```java
return Optional.fromNullable(myObject)
        .transform(new Function<MyObject, String> {
            @Override
            public String apply(MyObject input) {
                return input.foo();
            }
        })
        .or("default");
```

or, using Java 8 and lambdas :

```java
return Optional.fromNullable(myObject)
        .transform(MyObject::foo)
        .or("default");
```

If you don't already have an `Optional<MyObject>`, it's a bit convoluted for the same end result. The original version is simpler, as is the alternative using the ternary operator.